# Is the key legal, historical reason that marriage exists in the United States to regulate procreation?

Tags: united-states, history, law, marriage

During a recent radio show, at approximately [2 minutes and 30 seconds into the broadcast](http://www.wbur.org/npr/175273122/in-first-of-2-gay-marriage-cases-court-turns-to-proposition-8), [Charles Cooper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_J._Cooper) is quoted as saying the following in federal appeals court arguments:

> The key reason that marriage has existed at all in any society and at
> any time is that sexual relationships between men and women naturally
> produce children.

Which is quoted again in this [student newspaper](https://web.archive.org/web/20120227182948/http://xpress.sfsu.edu/archives/news/015928.html). This is being used in part as the basis for the legal argument against same-sex marriage in the United States.

This same argument was then used by Mr. Cooper to argue before the [Supreme Court of the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supreme_Court_of_the_United_States) in [case 12-144 on 26 March 2013](https://www.theatlantic.com/national/archive/2013/03/annotated-transcript-prop-8-oral-arguments/316946/) (see also [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170201092105/https://www.supremecourt.gov/oral_arguments/argument_transcripts/12-144.pdf)):

> JUSTICE KAGAN: Mr. Cooper, could I just understand your argument. In reading the briefs, it seems as though your principal argument is that same-sex and opposite — opposite-sex couples are not similarly situated because opposite-sex couples can procreate, same-sex couples cannot, and the State's principal interest in marriage is in regulating procreation. Is that basically correct?
>
> MR. COOPER: I — Your Honor, that's the essential thrust of our — our position, yes.

My issue is with the first part of the argument, namely that the *key legal reason* that marriage exists is due to procreation given the very wide brush that is used (i.e. all societies at any time in history). Is this in fact definitely the case or did Mr. Cooper in fact use too broad of a brush and there are notable historical exceptions to his claim?

Comment: @rjzii: I have a real problem making sense of the question altogether. I simply cannot make the mental step from "marriage" to "procreation". The legal implications of a marriage, today, are taxation (at least in Germany), and some legal rights regarding e.g. being allowed to visit your spouse in the ICU and getting medical information, or rulings regarding divorce. Most "procreation" related laws work outside of wedlock just as well. So I don't see where the point about marriage -> procreation is supposed to be, meaning I can't really tell whether that is the "key" point...

Comment: (ctd.) I also don't see where the state does "manage" procreation (unless we're talking China's "one child per family" policy. So... what are the claimants actually talking about? (Other than "we feel same-sex marriages are gross and are grasping for straws to keep them non-legal"?)

Comment: I see a huge difference between (a) the principal reason the cultural practice of marriage exists is to ensure any children are cared for - this is likely impossible to answer and (b) State's principal interest in legislating marriage is in regulating procreation - this is likely very hard to answer too.

Comment: @DevSolar You might want to refer back to the question since I narrowed the scope down to just the United States where the argument was made in the context of legalization of same-sex marriage. This is the argument that was made by lawyers in the case, but my understanding is that there is no historical basis for the claim, thus the question here.

Comment: @Oddthinking It's a tough question to answer, but I don't think it's impossible give that we've had a couple attempts at it. Given more free time of my own I might spend a bit hitting the stacks since my hunch is that marriage laws in the US are derived from British common law, which was more about inheritance and next-of-kin than anything else.

Comment: @rjzii: I still don't get the line of thought followed by the claimants in the first place. "Marriage exists because of procreation, which the state wants to control." Huh? I beg your pardon? I don't even understand *what is being claimed*. It sounds like totally disjunct rambling.

Comment: @rjzii: I don't think the current attempts at answering it are strong answers at all. If anything they are evidence that the question is difficult or impossible to answer.

Comment: @DevSolar Are you familiar with the Hollingsworth v. Perry case? There's a bit of situational knowledge that is needed to be able to follow the case.

Comment: @Oddthinking I haven't actually sat down and read the ruling, but that alone might be sufficient. If one of the SCOTUS justices said "give me a break" to argument then not much more needs to be said in the sense of US law at least.

Comment: @DevSolar You might want to read the transcript in "The Atlantic" as well, the justices had a field day with Coopers argument.

Comment: @rjzii: I don't think reading up on court cases and transcripts elsewhere should be necessary to make sense of a SE question...

Comment: @DevSolar The distilled question is in the title, everything else I wrote five years ago was supporting that was the point the lawyers were actually trying to make. Also, don't try to read too much into it, the legal argument is actually pretty clear. The lawyers arguing for Prop 8 where literally saying that the reason why marriage exists in the US is to regulate procreation. As such, the state has a vested interest in preventing couples who cannot procreate from getting married.

Comment: @rjzii: Well, as I am severely disagreeing on that very point, perhaps you can see where I am coming from. It's nonsense, plain and simple.

Comment: @DevSolar It's a tenuous legal argument at best.

Comment: @Oddthinking Just wrote up a long answer that might be the best possible, Obergefell v. Hodges pretty much answers the argument for us. A comments clean-up might be in order.

Comment: @DevSolar "I simply cannot make the mental step from "marriage" to "procreation"." You inability to make this step is  bizarre. Perhaps current German culture does not associate marriage closely with procreation, but clearly the two historically have been connected.

Comment: @Acccumulation: "Historically" is a broad term. Note that, at the time I wrote that comment, the question was not yet limited to "in the United States" and the passage "any society and at any time" stood more prominently. *Historically* marriage was a concept that appeared at about the same time as the shift from hunter/gatherer to farming societies, as a means to handle *ownership* and *inheritance* of land. (ctd.)

Comment: Today, the condemnation of procreation out of wedlock is (so I hope) on its way out, as is the condemnation of same-sex partnerships or the linking of certain rights (e.g. visitation) to marriage instead of stated will. Let's say I am taking a wider view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The case in question is [Hollingsworth v. Perry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollingsworth_v._Perry) (2013) which ended up being a key court decision allowing for same-sex marriage in California and is closely related to [Obergefell v. Hodges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obergefell_v._Hodges) (2015). The Supreme Court of the United States (SCOTUS) over turned [California Proposition 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Proposition_8_(2008)) (Prop 8) which defined marriage as being solely between a man and a woman.

When the case went before the SCOTUS a number of *[amicus curiae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amicus_curiae)* briefings were filed that argued, in essence, marriage is traditionally limited to opposite-sex couples because the government has vested interest in procreation. The [Family Research Council filed one example](https://downloads.frc.org/EF/EF13A111.pdf) of this arguing,

> The Court has recognized a substantive due process right to marry.
>   *Loving v.  Virginia*, 388 U.S.1 (1967), *Zablocki v. Redhail*, 434 U.S. 374 (1978), and *Turner v. Safley*, 482 U.S. 78 (1987).  But the
>   right recognized in these decisions all concerned opposite-sex, not
>   same-sex, couples.  *Loving*, 388 U.S. at 12, *Zablocki*, 434 U.S. at
>   384, *Turner*, 482 U.S. at 94-97.  That the right to marry is limited
>   to opposite-sex couples is clearly implied in a series of cases
>   relating marriage to procreation and child rearing.
>
> *See Skinner v. Oklahoma ex rel. Williamson*, 316 U.S. 535, 541 (1942) “Marriage and procreation are fundamental to the very existence and
>   survival of the race”); *Meyer v. Nebraska*, 262 U.S. 390, 399 (1923)
>   (liberty language in Due Process Clause includes “the right of the
>   individual . . . to marry, establish a home and bring up children”);
>   *Maynard v. Hill*, 125 U.S. 190, 211 (1888) (referring to marriage as “the foundation of the family and of society, without which there
>   would be neither civilization nor progress”).

This [argument first appeared in lower courts](http://www.arizonalawreview.org/pdf/53-3/53arizlrev913.pdf) where expert witness [Nancy Cott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nancy_F._Cott) noted that "marriage has never been universally defined as a union of one man and one woman, and that religion has never had any bearing on the legality of a marriage" ([transcript p.181-210](https://www.newsreview.com/media/blogpost/1351878/perry_1-11-10_ts.pdf)). [Legal interpretation of the argument](https://www.law.cornell.edu/supct/cert/12-144) also noted that the position was weak since Prop 8 was underinclusive since jurisprudence would require that it apply to opposite-sex couples that could not procreate. This position was echoed [by editorials](https://newrepublic.com/article/112778/supreme-court-gay-marriage-case-2013-laughable-argument) as well.

This point was then argued before the SCOTUS by Mr. Cooper on behalf of the Prop 8 supporters. The transcripts of the argument indicate that that the justices were skeptical, noting that opposite-sex couples that are incapable of procreation are still permitted to marry, [for example](https://www.theatlantic.com/national/archive/2013/03/annotated-transcript-prop-8-oral-arguments/316946/),

> [JUSTICE KAGAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elena_Kagan): Well, suppose a State said, Mr. Cooper, suppose a
>   State said that, Because we think that the focus of marriage really
>   should be on procreation, we are not going to give marriage licenses
>   anymore to any couple where both people are over the age of 55. Would
>   that be constitutional?
>
> MR. COOPER: No, Your Honor, it would not be constitutional.
>
> JUSTICE KAGAN: Because that's the same State interest, I would think,
>   you know. If you are over the age of 55, you don't help us serve the
>   Government's interest in regulating procreation through marriage. So
>   why is that different?
>
> MR. COOPER: Your Honor, even with respect to couples over the age of
>   55, it is very rare that both couples — both parties to the couple
>   are, and the traditional — (Laughter.)
>
> JUSTICE KAGAN: No, really, because if the couple — I can just assure
>   you, if both the woman and the man are over the age of 55, there are
>   not a lot of children coming out of that marriage.
>
> (Laughter.)
>
> MR. COOPER: Your Honor, society's — society's interest in responsible
>   procreation isn't just with respect to the procreative capacities of
>   the couple itself. The marital norm, which imposes the obligations of
>   fidelity and monogamy, Your Honor, advances the interests in
>   responsible procreation by making it more likely that neither party,
>   including the fertile party to that —
>
> JUSTICE KAGAN: Actually, I'm not even —
>
> [JUSTICE SCALIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonin_Scalia): I suppose we could have a questionnaire at the
>   marriage desk when people come in to get the marriage — you know, Are
>   you fertile or are you not fertile?

The difficulty in answering this question lies in the fact that the SCOTUS decided the case due to [lack of standing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollingsworth_v._Perry#U.S._Supreme_Court) by the petitioners as opposed to the merits of the case. Despite this it appears that the justices were highly skeptical of the argument as indicated by their questioning in the transcript.

The later Obergefell v. Hodges case actually gives us some context in which to interpret the SCOTUS decision though since the same argument was made. In the [slip opinion](https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/slipopinion/18) in which [the majority noted that](https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/14pdf/14-556_3204.pdf),

> The  respondents  also  argue  allowing  same-sex  couples to wed will
>   harm marriage as an institution by leading to  fewer  opposite-sex 
>   marriages.    This  may  occur,  the  respondents  contend,  because
>   licensing  same-sex  marriage severs  the  connection  between 
>   natural  procreation  and marriage.  That argument, however, rests on
>   a counterintuitive  view  of  opposite-sex  couple’s  decisionmaking
>   processes  regarding  marriage  and  parenthood.    Decisions about  whether  to  marry  and  raise  children  are  based  on many 
>   personal,  romantic,  and  practical  considerations;   and  it  is 
>   unrealistic  to  conclude  that  an  opposite-sex  couple  would 
>   choose  not  to  marry  simply  because  same-sex   couples may do so.
>   See *Kitchen v. Herbert*, 755 F. 3d 1193,  1223  (CA10  2014)  (“[I]t 
>   is  wholly  illogical  to  believe  that state  recognition  of  the 
>   love  and  commitment  between   same-sex couples will alter the most
>   intimate and personal decisions  of  opposite-sex  couples”).    The 
>   respondents  have not  shown  a  foundation  for  the  conclusion 
>   that  allowing   same-sex  marriage  will  cause  the  harmful 
>   outcomes  they   describe.    Indeed,  with  respect  to  this 
>   asserted  basis  for   excluding  same-sex  couples  from  the  right 
>   to  marry,  it  is appropriate  to  observe  these  cases  involve 
>   only  the  rights   of  two  consenting  adults  whose  marriages 
>   would  pose  no   risk of harm to themselves or third parties.

...thus noting the legal coupling between marriage and procreation, although arguing that procreation cannot be the sole basis for marriage since opposite-sex couples have "many personal,  romantic,  and  practical  considerations." The dissenting argument by [Justice Roberts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Roberts) also notes that,

> The premises supporting this concept of marriage are so fundamental 
>   that  they  rarely  require  articulation.    The   human race must
>   procreate to survive.  Procreation occurs  through  sexual  relations 
>   between  a  man  and  a  woman. When  sexual  relations  result  in 
>   the  conception  of  a  child, that  child’s  prospects  are 
>   generally  better  if  the  mother and  father  stay  together  rather
>   than  going  their  separate   ways.    Therefore,  for  the  good  of
>   children  and  society,   sexual  relations  that  can  lead  to 
>   procreation  should  occur only  between  a  man  and  a  woman 
>   committed  to  a  lasting   bond.

Further noting that,

> This  singular  understanding  of  marriage  has  prevailed   in the
>   United States throughout our history.  The majority accepts  that  at 
>   “the  time  of  the  Nation’s  founding  [marriage]  was  understood 
>   to  be  a  voluntary  contract  between  a man and a woman.” 
>   *Ante*, at 6.  Early Americans drew heavily  on  legal  scholars  like  William  Blackstone,  who regarded  marriage  between  “husband  and 
>   wife”  as  one  of  the  “great  relations  in  private  life,”  and 
>   philosophers  like John Locke, who described marriage as “a voluntary
>   compact between man and woman” centered on “its chief end,
>   procreation”  and  the  “nourishment  and  support”  of  children. 1  W.  Blackstone,  Commentaries  *410;  J.  Locke,  Second  Treatise 
>   of  Civil  Government  §§78–79,  p.  39  (J.   Gough  ed.  1947). To  those  who  drafted  and  ratified  the   Constitution, this
>   conception of marriage and family “was a  given:  its  structure,  its
>   stability,  roles,  and  values  accepted  by  all.”   Forte,  The 
>   Framers’  Idea  of  Marriage  and   Family,  in  The  Meaning  of 
>   Marriage  100,  102  (R.  George   & J. Elshtain eds. 2006).

In a similar dissenting argument, [Justice Alito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Alito) notes that,

> If this traditional understanding of the purpose of marriage does not
>   ring true to all ears today, that is probably because  the  tie 
>   between  marriage  and  procreation  has frayed.

As such, we may conclude that the justices accept as legal fact one of the purposes of marriage is to legitimize children that result from a couple. However, the majority decision in Obergefell v. Hodges **rejects** the legal argument that the *sole* legal and historical reason for marriage in the United States is to regulate procreation.

Answer (score 11):

**No it isn't**.

Your [first source](http://www.wbur.org/npr/175273122/in-first-of-2-gay-marriage-cases-court-turns-to-proposition-8) states by itself that in the state of California any two people can get married, as long as they are of the opposite sex, even if they can't bring forth children, such as elderly couples and even prisoners.

More over, ***the Jewish law***, on which the Judeo-Christian marriage is based says the following things:

Inability to bring children after 10 years of marriage is a reason to force divorce, but only for the man, and only if he doesn't have children already.

However, through history this was not enforced for couples that didn't want to get a divorce, even if their community wanted them to divorce. On the other hand, other couples used this as an excuse, even though they had **other** reasons to get a divorce.

The source tells about two separate occasions, one that was brought before [Maimonides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides), where the community wanted to force a divorce on a childless couple, even though the couple didn't want to, and they were allowed to stay together if they wanted.

The other case, was in Tunis, where a case was presented to [Rabi Itzhak Bar Sheshet Parpat](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/toshba/biyograf/ribash.htm) (1326-1408), where a man with no children wanted to marry a 90 year old woman. The community wanted to stop the marriage on this cause, because they claimed that he was only after her money. The marriage however was allowed.

The source summarizes by saying that by law a couple must separate if they didn't have children after 10 years of marriage; however this was not enforced by Rabbis.

Also I want to add that it only valid for men with no children, so women and men that already have children can marry into a childless marriage.

The source for it is [this page](https://www.biu.ac.il/JH/Parasha/eng/toledot/shi.html) (also: [Hebrew Version](http://www.biu.ac.il/jh/parasha/toldot/shi.html)) written by Dr. Yoel Shiloh of Ashkelon College. The page shows its sources for each and every claim it makes, including citations from the sources.

***The Catholic Church***, also, doesn't see infertility as impediment to marriage:

> Infertility (the inability to procreate children) is not an impediment to marriage

[source](https://www.catholic.com/qa/if-a-person-is-infertile-through-no-fault-of-his-own-can-he-get-married-in-the-catholic-church)

Comment: The claim is that the primary reason that the institution of marriage exists and that it is conveyed a legal benefit is that they tend to produce offspring.  The claim is not that that all marriages are expected to produce offspring.  So this answer does not address the claim.

Comment: @Chad, I do not agree with you. What I have showed is that even as far back as almost a 1000 years ago, people in traditional religious communities married for other reasons than procreation. So even if the concept of marriage was created to bear children (not sure that it's true), people have been using this institution for financial reasons, and partnership, **without the involvement of children at all**.

Comment: Your post is factually accurate. But it does not address the claim.  There is no claim that marriage is only about children.  Or that no one ever marries for anything else.  FYI Marraige goes back at least 5k years to the ancient Egyptians and Babylonians.  So all your answer shows is that for at the last 20% of the history of marriage there were other reasons.

Comment: Yes, Chad, exactly, my answer shows, that for the last 700 years, traditional marriage were used for reasons other than procreation. What the claimer (Cooper) says, is that traditional marriage can't stand marriage that don't result in children. While the opposite is true.

Comment: This claim is about the origin or marriage not what happend recently.

Comment: @Chad I don't think we have sources going back that far..

Comment: @BrendanLong - If you are saying that this is a bad question because of that then I agree.

Comment: ["By its very nature the institution of marriage and married love is ordered to the procreation and education of the offspring and it is in them that it finds its crowning glory."](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p2s2c3a7.htm) The Catholic Church most definitely considers procreation to be the primary purpose of marriage.

Comment: By my reading of Exodus and Leviticus, the primary purpose of marriage is to allow men who want to be certain of what children are theirs, to do so.  If none of the women with whom a man has relations, ever have relations with anyone else, that would imply that the man is the father of any children born to those women.  For a man to have relations with another man's wife nine months before she bears a child would create uncertainty as to whether the child was a proper heir; a severe offense meriting a severe penalty (death).

Comment: Note that if a married man were to have relations with prostitutes or other unmarried women who also had relationships with other men, such a man may have no way of knowing which if any of those womens' children were his, but since he would be both the instigator and victim of any consequent harm, there was no need for the law to prevent that.  Note also that no matter how promiscuous a husband may be, his wife would never have reason to question the motherhood of any child she carried.

Comment: @supercat, I'm not sure what you tried to say here. I just want to point out that in order to understand the Jewish law on any matter reading the Torah is not enough and one needs to learn and know the "Oral Torah"(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oral_Torah) and the Halacha set by rabbis.

Comment: @SIMEL: Exodus and Leviticus represent a codification of law which is thousands of years old.  By my reading, a major focus is on allowing a men a way of being able to produce heirs that will be known with certainty to be theirs.  Your post doesn't contradict that; if a man wants an heir and wife is barren, the law would allow him to use the services of another woman.  If, however, a man whose wife is barren is willing to accept the lack of an heir, that would be his prerogative.  Marriage doesn't represent an obligation to have children, but rather for a woman to refrain from having...

Comment: ...children by anyone other than her husband (or act in ways that would suggest that she might do so).

Comment: @supercat, again this is your interpretation of the scripture, it doesn't necessarily match the interpretation accepted today by most Jews. Also, it's a secular interpretation that assumes that religious laws serve a secular purpose. I'm not a religious man, but this is not the attitude of Jewish religious people, the approach is that religious laws are just facts meant to be followed without any other reason other than "God said so".

Comment: That is why I don't use the scriptures in the answer but rather an essay that summarizes what other rabbis said on the issue to avoid my interpretation which doesn't necessarily match the Halacha. If you want more info on this, I suggest trying Judaism.SE

Comment: @SIMEL: My point is not to imply or deny religious significance to the scriptures, but rather to cite them as evidence that a society thousands of years ago recognized and codified the notion that men should be able to have heirs with known paternity; such a notion is not a "Christian right wing" invention.

Comment: The question asks about why the institution of marriage was created. You're trying to change the subject to why people enter into marriage. Those are completely different questions.

Answer (score 8):

To answer the quote,

> The key reason that marriage has existed at all in any society and at any time is that sexual relationships between men and women naturally produce children.

I read that as true as far as it goes, if you mean "key *biological* reason" and not "key *legal* reason": 
I think we can agree than "men and women producing children" is a sine qua non of anything to do with multi-generational or historic human society ... without it there would be no human race, no society, no human customs (and no marriages).

> people would have no reason to get married if not for kids

I agree that societies require people who may have children (e.g. men and women) to marry: partly so they'd know who would look after the children and the wife.

People who couldn't have children (e.g. homosexuals) were not required to "marry" in the same way.

> My issue is with the first part of the argument, namely that the *key legal reason* that marriage exists

If you want to concentrate on *legal* reasons, marriage has evolved over millennia.

I would argue that the key and immediate reason is property: real estate, money, and [labour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labor_theory_of_value). There's evidence for my theory, for example:

- [Dowry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dowry)
- [Bride price](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bride_price)

Children (if they are born of the marriage) become part of that financial interconnection. I suggest that children are secondary in importance to property (i.e. that property is closer to being the "key legal reason").

However, I don't see how to prove that: because what you consider to be "the key" to a complex issue is perhaps subjective or a matter of opinion, or too narrow (because there's more than one 'key' reason), or too ill-defined (what does "key" mean in this context?).

A further, important (but perhaps more recent) reason why people choose to legally marry (as opposed to having a marriage forced on them by society) is [romantic love](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_(love)).

Comment: Perhaps this should be a comment and not an answer, as it's citations are just definitions on Wikipedia. (Even though I happen to think the response is well-reasoned.)

Answer (score 2):

The first statement is true but incomplete.

> The key reason that marriage has existed at all in any society and at any time is that sexual relationships between men and women naturally produce children.

The production of children is not in itself a sufficient reason for the institution of marriage. Rather it is [kinship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinship) that drives marriage (Wikipedia referenced for context, not evidence). In every society an individual exists within a web of kin relationships that create and manage mutual obligations. Marriage and parenthood are merely two types of kinship; there are many others.

The second statement is therefore incorrect.

> [...] the State's principal interest in marriage is in regulating procreation.

This is wrong. The state's interest is in regulating *kinship*. The regulation of procreation would not address marriage, rather it would address forms of sexual intercourse that might lead to childbirth, which is not the same thing.

[This article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1123651?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) from Columbia Law Review considers this question in more detail. From the abstract:

> While those justifications [of special status for sexual partners] revolve around the procreative potential of intercourse, it is the desire to limit procreation, rather than encourage it, that courts have invoked: The State's concern has been illegitimacy. Today, the prevalence and widespread acceptance of extramarital sex and birth control, accompanied by heightened respect for reproductive privacy, have rendered anachronistic the conception of marriage as a regulator of sex. The societal interests that remain are only loosely linked to intercourse, if at all: enforcing support obligations and stabilizing family units. Thus the continuing assumption that marriage is sexual--at the heart of the same-sex marriage debate and still embodied in law--has outlived its usefulness.

"*Enforcing support obligations and stabilizing family units*" is the regulation of kinship ties, in which the state has an ongoing interest.

Comment: Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5) to support your claims.

Comment: I've added one. However on reflection I'm thinking that there is a lot of scope for opinion in the original question.

Comment: @Oddthinking, I think the "opinion" scope for this question is very strong, due to the word "key".... the "key thing" is the thing that unlocks something, and in this context that is going to be something imminent, not something historical.  I suggest finding a question that's answerable on the history alone.

Comment: How would fatherhood be established in a society which didn't have either marriage or DNA testing?  While some forms of kinship (e.g. motherhood) could be established without marriage, I would regard fatherhood as an important form of kinship that, prior to the advent of DNA testing, was reliant upon marriage.  Are there any societies that have thrived for any length of time without recognizing the concept that a woman may be associated with exactly one man with whom she may have sexual relations, so as to guarantee that he will be the father of any children she bears?